# How do i set the response of a promise to a variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await

I have an async function that returns a value

```
  async getUsername(env:string,skuName: string,token:string): Promise<any> {
      let value =  await this.getDeviceName(env,skuName,token);
      return value;
  };
```

in another function, I am calling this get username function like this

```
let productN;
const prod = this.getUsername(env,skuName,token).then((resp) => {
    productN= resp;
    this.wait(300);
});
```

the variable productN is working, as i am able to see the response in my log, but when i try to use productN outside of this block, i am running into undefined.

```
 promotion = { 
    name: productN,
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end
 };
```

I am trying to set name to productN, and i just can not get it to work.

Can anyone explain to me what i am doing wrong please? Thanks

Comment: You can assign  value to `promotion.name` when you receive the response. like `promotion.name = resp`.

Comment: Because productN runs before your promise resolved. This is how javascript works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either assign to the `promotion` when you receive the response -

```
const prod = this.getUsername(env,skuName,token).then((resp) => {
    productN =  resp;
    promotion.name = resp
    this.wait(300);
});
```

Since your `getUsername` is asynchronous, you can wait for the response using `await` and then assign to `promotion` object.

```
(async() => {
  const resp = await this.getUsername(env,skuName,token);
  promotion = {
    name: resp,
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end
  } 
})();
```

--- Edit ---

```js
const input = [
    {
        env: 'lorem',
        skuname: 'skuname1',
        token: 'dummy'
    }, 
    {
        env: 'lorem',
        skuname: 'skuname2',
        token: 'dummy'
    }
];

const getUserName = (username) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(()=>resolve(username), 2000);
    });
};

(async () => {
    const resp = await Promise.all(input.map(({skuname}) => getUserName(skuname)));
    console.log(resp);
})();

// Or 

Promise.all(input.map(({skuname}) => getUserName(skuname)))
    .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
    });
```

Comment: hey @randomSoul, 

Thanks for the quick response, I tried both of your answers.... When i used the first one, only the last row in the table is picking up promotion.name, the first 10 row is undefined. 

When i tried the second one, all the data in the table were  blank.

Comment: promotion is an object. So every time you assign a new value previous value gets overridden. It seems like there exist multiple records, you can create an array of promises and then use `promise.all`. So once all of them gets executed you can show them in the table.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const productN = await this.getUsername(env,skuName,token);
console.log(productN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing this? Return your `getDeviceName` function in `getUsername`;

```
getUsername(env:string, skuName: string, token:string): Promise<any> {
  return this.getDeviceName(env, skuName, token);
};
const productN = await this.getUsername(env, skuName, token);
console.log(productN);
```

I don't know why you use `getUsername`. since you can get the value in `productN` directly from `getDeviceName`.

like

```
const productN = await this.getDeviceName(env, skuName, token);
```

If you want to do any other things inside `getUsername`. you can make it return a promise.

```
getUsername(env:string, skuName: string, token:string): Promise<any> {
 return New Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
  try {
   let value =  await this.getDeviceName(env,skuName,token);
   ...
   //all other things you want to do here 
   ...
   resolve(value);
  } catch (error) {
   reject(error)
  }
 }
};

const productN = await this.getUsername(env, skuName, token);
console.log(productN);
```

nb: I used `try catch` block for error handling, Ignore it if you don't want to.